# Webpack QuillJS outputs SVG path instead of inlining it

Tags: svg, webpack, quill

Im trying to install QuillJS with Symfony-Encore.
Somehow the SVG-Icons for the toolbar do not load as expected.

The output just shows the SVG`s path:

```
<span class="ql-formats">
    <button type="button" class="ql-bold">/build/images/bold.89e9c638.svg</button>
    <button type="button" class="ql-italic">/build/images/italic.b802b8f9.svg</button>
</span>
```

How do I resolve this path and embed or link the corresponding svg-icon?
I guess some kind of loader configuration is missing or smth like this.

I Embed Quill as separate components:

```
import Quill from 'quill/core';
// ... more quill packages
```

## Edit:

I added HTML-Loader to inline the svg`s into my HTML with this config:

```
{
    test: /\.svg$/,
    use: [{
        loader: 'html-loader',
        options: {
            minimize: true
        }
    }]
}
```

I'm now getting this error(s).

> These relative modules were not found:
>
> - ../assets/icons/align-left.svg in ./node_modules/quill/ui/icons.js
> - ../assets/icons/align-center.svg in ./node_modules/quill/ui/icons.js
> - ../assets/icons/align-right.svg in ./node_modules/quill/ui/icons.js
> - ../assets/icons/background.svg in ./node_modules/quill/ui/icons.js
> - ../assets/icons/align-justify.svg in ./node_modules/quill/ui/icons.js
>     ...

The paths theme correct. I totally don't know whats wrong here.

Thanks for your help :-)

Comment: Not sure why, but this fixes the issue
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60240231/1047510

Answer (score 2):

If your issue concerns Laravel Mix: [on GitHub there is a discussion](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/1423) about the problem in Mix itself, [and a solution](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/pull/1466#issuecomment-388007552) involving modifying your webpack.mix.js file as follows:

```
mix.extend('quill', webpackConfig => {
    const { rules } = webpackConfig.module;

    // 1. Exclude quill's SVG icons from existing rules
    rules.filter(rule => /svg/.test(rule.test.toString()))
        .forEach(rule => rule.exclude = /quill/);

    // 2. Instead, use html-loader for quill's SVG icons
    rules.unshift({
        test: /\.svg$/,
        include: [path.resolve('./node_modules/quill/assets')],
        loaders: [{ loader: 'html-loader', options: { minimize: true } }]
    });

    // 3. Don't exclude quill from babel-loader rule
    rules.filter(rule => rule.exclude && rule.exclude.toString() === "/(node_modules|bower_components)/")
        .forEach(rule => rule.exclude = /node_modules\/(?!(quill)\/).*/);
});

// …

mix.js(/* ... */)
   .quill()
```

Comment: Replaced step 2, the html loader part with this: 
`const quillIconsRegex = /node_modules\/quill\/assets\/icons\/(.*)\.svg$/`
`rules.push({
        test: quillIconsRegex,
        use: [{ loader: 'html-loader', options: { minimize: true } }],
    })`

Answer (score 2):

Just replace your import statement for `import Quill from 'quill'`.

I had the same issue and the problem was that using `import Quill from 'quill/core'` (or `import Quill from 'quill/quill'` in my case) was not importing all the necessary modules and assets, but just the Quill core in your case.

Comment: Thank you! This had me stumped, was doing from 'quill/quill' and it broke everything.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to disable the standard image loader by adding `.disableImagesLoader()` and add your own which excludes the Quill assets. I did the following, adapted from [this issue](https://github.com/symfony/webpack-encore/issues/393) which does it for CKEditor:

```
.disableImagesLoader()
.addRule({
    test: /\.(svg|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)/,
    exclude: /node_modules\/quill\/assets\/icons\/(.*)\.svg$/,
    use: [{
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
            filename: 'images/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
            publicPath: '/build/'
        }
    }]
})

.addLoader({
    test: /node_modules\/quill\/assets\/icons\/(.*)\.svg$/,
    loader: 'html-loader',
    options: {
        minimize: true
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you add svg to the allowed file extensions in the webpack config?

```
resolve: {
    // Which file extensions to load
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '*.js', '.css', '*.css', '.json', '*.json', '.svg', '*.svg'],
```

Answer (score 0):

I found solution here https://www.kohrvid.com/blog/posts/using-quilljs-with-rails-6

Just use `svg-inline-loader`